# Create subset of seqdef state object with reduced alphabet

Tags: r, traminer

Let's say we have sequences that consist of 5 different events/states (A-E) like this:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal)
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal, 13:24, alphabet=c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

Is it possible to now create a subset of actcal.seq that only contains for instance events A, C and E? If yes, then how is this done?

Clarification: I want to extract any sequence that contains A, C or E. If any of those contain B or D those events should be removed from the returned sequence. For instance, a sequence A-A-B-C-C-D-E-E should be returned as A-A-C-C-E-E.

Clarification 2: The input sequences should use the `alphabet=c("A","B","C","D","E")` while the modified sequence object I'm looking for should use the `alphabet=c("A","C","E")`. Some more examples as requested are given below:

```
"A-B-C-D-E" => "A-C-E"
"A-C-A-E" => "A-C-A-E"
"B-D" => NA or ""
"B-D-B-A-D" => "A"
```

I'll appreciate any solution on how to solve this without having to re-read a subset of the data from database.

Comment: Please clarify your question by being more explicit on what you expect. Do you want to extract the sequences that do not contain any B or D? Otherwise, what do you want to do with the B and D? Recode them as A, C, or E or treat them as missing values?

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing sample data of current and desired results.

Comment: I've clarified the question and added some examples of different input sequences and which results are desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recode states B and D as missing by means of the `seqrecode` function. The default symbol used for missing is `*`. I illustrate using only the first 10 sequences of `actcal`

```
data(actcal)
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal[1:10,13:24], alphabet=c("A","B","C","D","E"))

## Recode B and D as *, the default  missing symbol 
actcal.rec.seq <- seqrecode(actcal.seq, 
                     recodes = list("*"=c("B","D")), otherwise=NULL)

actcal.seq
#      Sequence               
# 2848 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 1230 D-D-D-D-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-D
# 2468 B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 654  C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-B-B-B
# 6946 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 1872 D-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B
# 2905 D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D
# 106  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 5113 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 4503 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A

actcal.rec.seq
#      Sequence               
# 2848 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
# 1230 *-*-*-*-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-*
# 2468 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
# 654  C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-*-*-*
# 6946 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 1872 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
# 2905 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
# 106  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 5113 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 4503 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
```

Dropping the missing states

```
actcal.rec.comp.seq <- seqdef(actcal.rec.seq, 
                          left="DEL", gap="DEL", right="DEL", 
                          missing="*", alphabet=c("A","C","E"))
```

Removing sequences that contain only missing

```
(rec.seq <- actcal.rec.comp.seq[!is.na(seqdur(actcal.rec.comp.seq)[,1]),])
#      Sequence               
# 2103 A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
# 3972 C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C      
# 5238 C                      
# 4977 C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C
# 528  A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
```

And if you want only the sequence of distinct successive states

```
seqdss(rec.seq)
#      Sequence
# 2103 A       
# 3972 C       
# 5238 C       
# 4977 C       
# 528  A
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the excellent description of how to solve the problem using `seqrecode()` and `seqdef()` with `DEL`.